# Replicating BUG ID to all Tortise Clients

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

We are using Visual SVN server and Tortise SVN client. We want to add BUG ID, to track all our checkins.

We could successfully do the same for one of the client machines which has Tortise SVN Client. But the same is not getting replicated to other machines.

How to setup the BUG ID at VisualSVN server so that all client machines will get replicated with BUG ID option.

How to make BUG ID field as mandatory (as of now it is prompting for one option with 'proceed without BUG ID' this option shouldn't prompt).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't.

Longer answer: Subversion does not have a facility built in by which you can control client configuration via the server.

Things you *can* do (I'm assuming you're doing [this](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html)?):

- Apply the appropriate properties to your tree such that your clients all pick up the settings, use them, and apply them to subsequently-created folders. But this breaks down when someone uses any client other TortoiseSVN.
- Install a pre-commit hook script on the server to reject any commit that lacks the BUG ID in the appropriate format/with the required data, and gives the committer a message informing them of why their commit was rejected so that they can fix it.